# Cordova geolocation timestamp

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Timestamp(location.getTime()) returned by this plugin is same as mobile device and not of GPS server. I have tested the same on Android 5 version. Please advise.

Given below is the code.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

var onSuccess = function(position) {
                          $scope.currentPosition.lat = position.coords.latitude;
                  $scope.currentPosition.lon = position.coords.longitude;
                   $scope.currentPosition.timestamp = position.timestamp;
            alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
                  'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
                  'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
                  'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
                  'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
                  'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
                  'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
                  'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n' +
                  'Date time: '         + new Date(position.timestamp)      + '\n');

        };
```

I need to store this position.timestamp for some purpose but it is giving mobile time and not of GPS server. User can manipulate this time which will defeat the application purpose. Let me know if any more info is required.

Comment: please specify your problem clearly.

Comment: @ChitrankDixit Updated the problem, plz advise.